# I can't allign my div to the bottom of its parent

Tags: css

I have a div that i don't know how to allign to the bottom of its parent.

I tried with bottom: 0 and margin-bottom: 0 but both doesn't work. I played with position aswell and it doesn't change anything only the absolute position makes the div stick to the very bottom of the page. Vertical-align doesn't seem to work aswell.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```css
.category{
        height: 70px !important;
        width: 28% !important;
        margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
        border: 1px solid #3A94D7;
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.75), inset 0 0 2px 0 #4293D5;
    }
    .icon-steam{
        background: url(../img/steam.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
     background-size: 40px;
        float: left;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        margin-right: 0.3em;
    }
    .platform{
     text-shadow: none;
     color: #65a1bf;
     text-align: center;
      bottom: 0;
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories">
   <div class="category icon-steam"><div class="platform">Steam</div></div>
  </div>
```

And there's a fiddle link if you want: https://jsfiddle.net/kk8Lwh6v/

Can someone help me please?

Comment: do you want the entire div should bottom of the page, or that Steam text should be bottom of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:absolute` on the element that you want to align and add `position:relative` on its parent.

```css
.category {
  height: 70px !important;
  width: 28% !important;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #3A94D7;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75), inset 0 0 2px 0 #4293D5;
  position: relative;
}

.icon-steam {
  background: url(../img/steam.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px;
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}

.platform {
  width: 100%;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #65a1bf;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <div class="category icon-steam">
    <div class="platform">Steam</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) properties:

```css
.category {
  height: 70px !important;
  width: 28% !important;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #3A94D7;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75), inset 0 0 2px 0 #4293D5;
}

.icon-steam {
  background: url(../img/steam.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px;
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.platform {
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #65a1bf;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <div class="category icon-steam">
    <div class="platform">Steam</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```css
.category{
    height: 70px !important;
    width: 28% !important;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #3A94D7;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.75), inset 0 0 2px 0 #4293D5;
}
.icon-steam{
    background: url(../img/steam.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
 background-size: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 0.3em;
}
.platform{
 text-shadow: none;
 color: #65a1bf;
 left:14%;
  top:60px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
  <div class="categories">
   <div class="category icon-steam"><div class="platform">Steam</div></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.category{
    height: 70px !important;
    width: 28% !important;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #3A94D7;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.75), inset 0 0 2px 0 #4293D5;
}
.icon-steam{
    background: url(../img/steam.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 0.3em;
}
.platform{
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #65a1bf;
    text-align: center;
  top: 60px;
  left:14%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
        <div class="category icon-steam"><div class="platform">Steam</div></div>
    </div>
```